# Javascript short circuit if statement: How to return true

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function which check the value if `null` or `""`

Here is what I got so far (that is working)

```
function notnull(values,success,failed){
var count = 0

$.each(values,function(index,val){
    console.log(val)
    val != "" && val != null ? count++ : count 
})
if(count == values.length){
    return true;
}else{
    console.log('false')
}
}
```

However If I tried short circuiting the 2nd `if` statement it returns an error

```
function notnull(values,success,failed){
var count = 0

$.each(values,function(index,val){
    val != "" && val != null ? count++ : count
})(count == values.length) ? return true:console.log('false')
}
```

the error says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Question 1: How can I return `true` or `false` in a short circuit version

Question 2: at the code

```
val != "" && val != null ? count++ : count
```

How can I omit the else part?

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach? What you are trying in the 2nd is completely invalid syntax. `return` can only be the first keyword in a statement.

Comment: `function notnull( values, usused1, unused2 ) { return values.filter( x => x ).length !== 0 }`

Comment: and if you really wanted one that checks if anything at all is null: `function anynull( values ) { return values.filter( x => x ).length !== values.length }`

Comment: The above depends on the JavaScript behavior of filter to test the return value of the filter function for "truthiness".  `""`, `0`, `false`, `undefined`, `NaN` and `null` are all "not truthy"

Comment: another issue with your code, do you understand what `$.each()` returns? it's not a function, so, you'd get an error at runtime anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is a bit messy, but if I understand your function, you want to go through each value and make sure none of them are null, right?

Here is your original, cleaned up a bit:

```
function notNull(values){
  let count = 0;

  $.each(values, function (index,val) {
    (val != "" && val != null) ? count++ : count 
  });

  return count == values.length; // returns true or false
}
```

You are basically going through each of the values, counting them up if they aren't null, and returning `true` if none were null (your count is the same as your array) or `false` otherwise.

You are using the `jQuery` equivalent of the vanilla `each()` function. They function the same way: they'll go through every single entry in an array.

You can't short-circuit `each()`. Instead, you need to use `some()` or `every()`. Those functions are similar, but opposite:

- `some()` - Continues to loop through as long as its callback returns **false**.
- `every()` - Continues to loop through as long as its callback returns **true**.

In your case, you want to use `every()` because you want to go through *every* element and make sure it is something (in your case, not null):

```js
function notNull(values) {
  return values.every((value) => value != "" && value != null);
}

console.log(notNull([1,2,3]));
console.log(notNull([1,null,3]));
```

Much nicer. This will check each value. As long as they match the condition, it'll keep going and ultimately return `true`. If if finds one that does match, it'll short circuit there and return `false`.

---

As for your second question, how can you leave out the "else" part of this:

```
val != "" && val != null ? count++ : count
```

With the `ternary operator` (?:), you can't. But, you can with the normal boolean operators:

```
val != "" && val != null && count++;
```

JavaScript will short-circuit that condition at the first `false`, so it'll only get to `count++` if the other two bits are true.

---

On your second example, I think you were attempting something like:

```
condition ? return value : console.log('a')
```

This would be an invalid syntax. You can only have values inside of a ternary. You could do something like this:

```
return condition ? value : otherValue;
```

If you want a `return` mixed in, you have to do it as two separate things:

```
!condition && console.log(''); // log if false;
if (condition) return value;
```

`return` and `throw` are both stubborn in this way and always have to be broken out and can't be mixed with other selective operators.